# Get response of action as a promise (like redux-thunk)

Tags: redux-thunk, redux-saga

I am moving from redux-thunk to redux-saga but was finding one deficiency.

With redux-thunk I had a very typical way of doing "add requests":

```
try {
    downloadId = await dispatch(requestDownload('SOME_URL'));
} catch(ex) {
    console.log('download already existed, so request denied');
}
```

That action would return a promise, which I could wait on. The `request` function (`requestDownload` above) would either grant the request, and resolve with a `downloadId` or it would reject, if the download for that `SOME_URL` already existed.

How can I do this in redux-saga? It seems actions cannot return anything.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `redux-saga` you are not using `await` but `yield` in combination with `effects` instead.

Your code could look like this:

```
// saga.js

import { call, put } from 'redux-saga/effects'
import { requestDownloadSucceeded, requestDownloadFailed } from './reducer.js'

function* downloadRequestedFlow() {
  try {
    const downloadId = yield call(requestDownload, 'SOME_URL')

    yield put(requestDownloadSucceeded(downloadId))
  } catch(error) {
    yield put(requestDownloadFailed(error))
  }
}


// reducer.js
...
export const requestDownloadSucceeded = downloadId => ({
  type: REQUEST_DOWNLOAD_SUCCEEDED,
  downloadId,
})

export const requestDownloadFailed = error => ({
  type: REQUEST_DOWNLOAD_FAILED,
  error,
})
```

Note the generator function with a `*` that allows the usage of yield. I'm also using the common `REQUESTED`, `SUCCEEDED`, `FAILED` pattern here.

I hope this answer was helpful.

Comment: Thanks @Alex - but i need to know if the initial `dispatch(action)` was succesful. In redux-thunk, my action would fail if the `isFetching`/`isDownloading` is true, my action would check the `state`.

Comment: Your `requestDownload` method returns a promise. It makes the service request and resolves with `downloadId` and rejects with `error` that is then catched in the `catch` block.

Comment: Wow totally forgot to accept this. This really helped me understand sagas.